# Run task's "problemMatcher" on console/terminal output

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

Is there a way to run a problem matcher on output programmatically? I'd make a certain command (compile files to DB) and then runnnig problem matcher on recevied console/terminal output, as an extension command.

I could expose a task with custom problem matcher If I could reach command from task. (feature-request [#11396](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11396))

Is there maybe some other way to pass "non-shell" commands through problem matcher in extension? Or maybe run a task inside extension? 
Anything that would make it work... :)